# How to ensure Mongoose schema structure

Tags: mongoose

With Mongoose, we can ensure that **leaf paths** are of a certain type: `new Schema({name: String})`and `user.name = {}` will fail validation. Good.

But let's say now I change the schema to `new Schema({name: {first:String, last:String}})`. running `user.name="Tyler";user.save()` validates just fine. Seems schema integrity validation only applies to leaf paths, not to root/intermediate paths (aka, not to schema *structure*)

There a way to trigger validation errors here?

Comment: Incidentally, this doesn't work either: `schema.path('name').validate(function(v){ return typeof v === 'object' }, err)`. Throws `Cannot call method 'validate' of undefined`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mongoose also supports some more schema validation other than leaf types, see [here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html) for the details:

> Mongoose has several built in validators.
>
> - All SchemaTypes have the built in required validator
> - Numbers have min and max validators
> - Strings have enum and match validators

Namely the required validator could be used to solve the problem described in the question:

```
new Schema({
    name: {
        first: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        } , 
        last: {
            type: String,
            required:true
        }
     }
})
```

If the built-in validations are not suficient then there is also the possibility of writing custom validators, using for example [mongoose-validator](https://github.com/leepowellcouk/mongoose-validator).

Comment: Good thinking on the `required` idea. I thought about it, tried it, it worked - then backed out thinking "that can't be the right approach". Now you mention it and I think on it more thoroughly, I think it's actually a pretty decent approach.